# Ubuntu 18.04 Compiling opencv 3.4.3 python 3.5 error: ImportError: libjasper.so.4

Tags: python, python-3.x, opencv, anaconda, conda

I have built opencv from source, and have tried to import in a simple program in python, and i get this:

```
Python 3.5.5 |Anaconda custom (64-bit)| (default, May 13 2018, 21:12:35) 
Type 'copyright', 'credits' or 'license' for more information
IPython 6.4.0 -- An enhanced Interactive Python. Type '?' for help.

In [1]: import cv2
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-c8ec22b3e787> in <module>()
----> 1 import cv2

ImportError: libjasper.so.4: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

Note: I'm using a conda env.

Comment: Please don't post code/terminal output in images. See here for why: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/2449192

Answer (score 0):

If you're relying on instructions that claim that the only way to get opencv is to build from source, it's possible those instructions predate `opencv-python` being installable via pip.

If there's a reason you have to build from source, here's what I had to install to build opencv from source two years ago (for Ubuntu 16.04). The list might be stale.

```
sudo apt-get install -y build-essential cmake pkg-config
sudo apt-get install -y libjpeg8-dev libtiff4-dev libjasper-dev libpng12-dev
sudo apt-get install -y libavcodec-dev libavformat-dev libswscale-dev libv4l-dev
sudo apt-get install -y libgtk2.0-dev
sudo apt-get install -y libatlas-base-dev gfortran
```

Comment: I'm facing a problem to use detectMultiScale, when I call this method the kernel(jupyter notebook's kernel) simply dies.